# Jenkins email-ext plugin thinks I have no recipients configured

Tags: email, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins 2.2 and [email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) 2.42 (both current, as are all of the rest of my plugins).  I have my global configuration set to have a single, explicit recipient and my project is using default email notification configuration (that is, send to $DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS).  I have also set an explicit recipient in the project.  In both configurations, the console output for the job says:

> An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.

This would seem to be https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13583 except
1. that was marked as resolved four years ago, and 2. I get e-mail when I use basic, built-in notifications.  Does anyone else see this problem with email-ext?

Comment: Buried in the docs, there is a `to:` parameter so you can just specify recipient(s) without the bother of figuring out the `recipientProviders` complexities.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Turns out plugin configuration is somewhat non-intuitive; a necessary setting is buried behind an Advanced button.  I got answers in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34731 and it is working now as follows:

In the Advanced settings, Triggers -> Failure - Any lists "Developers" by default, but not "Recipient List."

Comment: Thanks Chris. Can you state the config you are referring to?

Comment: In the Advanced settings, Triggers -> Failure - Any lists "Developers" by default, but not "Recipient List."

Comment: Advanced Settings of what, "Extended E-mail Notification"? If its what we are talking about, this answer is probably outdated because there is no setting for Trigger->Failure.

Comment: I can confirm this answer is still true. The advance settings is for Editable Email Notification.

Comment: To the people who are confused, there is advanced settings in both the Manage Jenkins page and also, in project configure section of Editable email Notification. You have to remove the developer option and add Recipient list in The advanced section of the email notification of a job

Comment: No grammatically clear instruction and no actual explanation of the underlying issue

Answer (score 4):

For those using this plugin in combination with Job DSL. I have do add the `sendTo { recipientList() }` block explicitly to the different triggers.

So my DSL looked like this:

```
extendedEmail {
    recipientList('${EMAIL_RECIPIENTS}')
    triggers {
        failure {
            subject('The subject')
            content("The content")
            sendTo {
                recipientList()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS` use `to:`

```
emailext(
    to: 'somename@emailprovider.com',
    body: '${DEFAULT_CONTENT}', 
    mimeType: 'text/html',
    subject: '${DEFAULT_SUBJECT}',
    replyTo: '$DEFAULT_REPLYTO'    
    )
}
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39499554/1134084

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem through repeated attempts. There is no need for such trouble at all. The reason is that in the advanced Settings of Editable Email Notification trigger condition, the Recipient List is empty by default, and all your Settings outside will be overridden. An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients was ignored. An attempt to send an E-mail to empty list of recipients ignored.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was using a noreplay address for the to field and recipientProviders like culprits for the developers with attached logs and it was working:

```
emailext to: 'noreplay@xxx.yyy',
              recipientProviders: [culprits()],
              subject: 'Jenkins-Build has failure: $PROJECT_NAME - #$BUILD_NUMBER',
              body: 'Check console output at $BUILD_URL to view the results. \n\n ${CHANGES}',
              attachLog: 'true',
              attachmentsPattern: 'bin/log/compile.log'
```