# How to get same Mailer behaviour for Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I started using Jenkins declarative pipelines. Now I want to have the same email notification behavior as defined in the [Usage](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mailer)  of the Mailer plugin:

> 1. Every failed build triggers a new e-mail.
> 2. A successful build after a failed (or unstable) build triggers a new e-mail, indicating that a crisis is over.
> 3. An unstable build after a successful build triggers a new e-mail, indicating that there's a regression.
> 4. Unless configured, every unstable build triggers a new e-mail, indicating that regression is still there.

I read about [Notifications in Pipelines](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Using-multiple-steps,-stages-and-notifications), but it does not notify based on above rules. Plus it does not contain part of the console output in the message body in case of a build failure.

Does anybody know how to do this in declarative pipeline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the following code you can use the mailer plugin in the post section. This provides the expected behaviour:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
      stage('test') {
        steps {
          script {
              // change to 'UNSTABLE' OR 'FAILED' to test the behaviour 
              currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
          }
        }
      }
  }
  post {
        always {
          step([$class: 'Mailer',
            notifyEveryUnstableBuild: true,
            recipients: "test@test.com",
            sendToIndividuals: true])
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is important to set `currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'` at the beginning of the pipeline, otherwise the emails are not sent out, see [Mailer inside Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37169100/use-jenkins-mailer-inside-pipeline-workflow).

Comment: You're right, currentBuild.result is not automatically set in the post section of the pipeline. It might be better so set currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS' at the very end of the job. E.g. at the beginning of the post section. See my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44329032/how-to-send-back-to-normal-notifications-in-jenkins-declarative-pipeline