# notifications are not sent after build

Tags: jenkins

I want to send build results - whether it is `SUCCESS` or `FAILURE` to some recipients. In `Extended E-mail Notification` config I set reply to list to some `gmail` mail.

[image]

In my `after build` section for `notification` of the job I left notification config as is

[image]

But when build fails it does not send notification as recipients list is considered `empty`.

[image]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you fill the **Default Recipients** inside "Extended E-Mail Notification" and use as Project Recipient List `$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS` or you specify directly the e-mail adresses (comma seperated) inside the **Project Recipient List**

One of the both fields must contain a valid e-mail adress. Otherwhise it will fail with `An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.` failure.

Additionaly try to verify: [Jenkins email-ext plugin thinks I have no recipients configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37144078/jenkins-email-ext-plugin-thinks-i-have-no-recipients-configured)

Comment: I set `default recipients` to empty and set `project recipient list` to `example@gmail.com` and it still considers recipient list empty

Comment: Since your screenshots showed different settings, I wrote this answer. Are you sure the error message is the same?

Comment: well I adjusted according to your comment and it is the samel `An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: FAILURE`

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37144078/jenkins-email-ext-plugin-thinks-i-have-no-recipients-configured . Short: In the Advanced settings, Triggers -> Failure - Any lists "Developers" by default, but not "Recipient List."

Comment: wow indeed. Now it works! Thanks! P.S. though I did not get the email it at least showed that it sent it